# Checking Kafka Cache against a particular field

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka topic that is receiving message. Now my consumer receives an object having various fields lets say id and name. After some i receive another object and so on . After some time i want to check that object with id = {some number} is present in cache of kafka or not. So is there a way to check kafka cache against a particular field.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking of two different consumers here, Consumer-1 which is just consuming the message from Kafka topic doing some processing based on your logic .

Consumer-2 which given consumes all the messages in the topic from beginning and matches them against a set of id(s).

The second case will become more and more expensive as messages are added to the topic. This is not the use case Kafka is built for, you could do this more effectively in ActiveMQ.

If you still want to use Kafka the other option is you could maintain a small in memory Hashset of records against which you can do the comaprison.